# python json unicode - how do I eval using javascript

Tags: python, json, unicode, cgi

Really spent a lot of time searching for this. Please need some help.

I am trying to add multilingual feature to my web app framework. For this I am unable to send non ascii characters as JSON. Here is what I am doing

1. Here is what I get from the database

   '\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xa4'

   which when I print gives me which is okay

   तेस्त
2. I make the response object

   response = {'a':'\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xa4'}
3. Send the repsonse

   import json

   sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(response))
4. This is what it prints

   Returns u'{"a": "\u0924\u0947\u0938\u094d\u0924"}'

Any help, pointers will be welcome

Thanks!

Rushabh

Comment: Seems a tricky question. It's better to ask stackoverflow guys, how they are handling this तेस्त

Answer (score 4):

Is this your desired output (see `ensure_ascii` argument for [`json.dumps`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps))?

```
sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False))
{"a": "तेस्त"}
```