# Json parsing with unicode characters

Tags: json, unicode

i have a json file with unicode characters, and i'm having trouble to parse it. I've tried in Flash CS5, the JSON library, and i have tried it in http://json.parser.online.fr/ and i always get "unexpected token - eval fails"

I'm sorry, there realy was a problem with the syntax, it came this way from the client.

Can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that it's a unicode issue, and not a problem with the json data itself ? (syntax error, incomplete file...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quoth the RFC:](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8.

So a correctly encoded Unicode character should not be a problem. Which leads me to believe that it's *not* correctly encoded (maybe it uses latin-1 instead of UTF-8). How did you create the file? In a text editor?

Answer (score 2):

There might be an obscure Unicode whitespace character hidden in your string.

This URL contains more detail:

http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset

Comment: the URL does not work anymore (error 502) :(

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net you would think you would use System.Text.Encoding to convert a string like "Paul\u0027s" back to a string like "Paul's" but i tried for hours and found nothing that worked.

The trouble is hardcoding a string as shown above already decodes the string as you will see if you put a break point on it so in the end i wrote a function that converts the Hex27 to Dec39 so that i ended up with HTML encodeing and then decoded that.

```
 string Padding = "000";
                for (int f = 1; f <= 256; f++)
                {
                    string Hex = "\\u" + Padding.Substring(0, 4 - f.ToString().Length) + f;
                    string Dec = "&#" + Int32.Parse(f.ToString(), NumberStyles.HexNumber) + ";";
                    HTML = HTML.Replace(Hex, Dec);
                }
                HTML = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HTML);
```

Ugly as sin, I know but without using the latest framework (Not on ISP's server) it was the best I could do and someone must know a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just change the file encoding type Mac-Roman/windows-1252 to UTF-8.. and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Twitter json files. I was parsing them in Python with json.loads(tweet) but it failed for half of the records.

I changed to Python3 and it works well now.

Answer (score 0):

If you seem to have trouble with the encoding of a JSON file (i.e. escaped codes such as `\u00fc` aren't displayed correctly regardless of your editor's encoding setting) generated by Python with [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) [`s`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)`()`: it encodes ASCII by default and escapes the unicode characters! See [python json unicode - how do I eval using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019966/python-json-unicode-how-do-i-eval-using-javascript) (and [python: json.dumps can't handle utf-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184108/python-json-dumps-cant-handle-utf-8) and [Why does json.dumps escape non-ascii characters with "\uxxxx"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411965/why-does-json-dumps-escape-non-ascii-characters-with-uxxxx)).