# PHP twitter rss and Arabic Characters

Tags: php, twitter, json

I am trying to get rss tweets of user in twitter by using the API 1.1 , all work fine, I get the json result , but the problem is that the tweets is written in arab, so I get some thing like that  \u0648 \u0641\u0650 ... 
I tried this `$json = json_encode($json);` but still no result

I use not php 5.4 so I cannot use `$test = json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

any help please.

Comment: if you're getting json back from the api, you probably want to **DECODE** it with json_decode, not re-encode it.

Comment: I try it , still not working

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901133/json-and-escaping-characters) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019327/json-parsing-with-unicode-characters) of assistance.  As Mike Baranczak points out in his response to the second of those questions, JSON is supposed to be encoded in Unicode.  Which means the account you're grabbing the data of has done something really dumb with ASCII escape characters to make the Arabic script appear in all places or has done something odd with the Twitter client they're using.

By the way, if it's the account that I think it is, it's just posting verses from the Quran.  You'll know if it's the account I suspect it is if the screen name (username) is also in Arabic, in addition to the "real name" on the account.  If it is that account, don't worry about it and save yourself the headache.