# Why does json.dumps escape non-ascii characters with "\uxxxx"

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-2.x

In Python 2, the function `json.dumps()` will ensure that all non-ascii characters are escaped as `\uxxxx`.

[Python 2 Json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage)

But isn't this quite confusing because `\uxxxx` is a unicode character and should be used inside a unicode string.

The output of `json.dumps()` is a `str`, which is a byte string in Python 2. And thus shouldn't it escape characters as `\xhh` ?

```
>>> unicode_string = u"\u00f8"
>>> print unicode_string
ø
>>> print json.dumps(unicode_string)
"\u00f8"
>>> unicode_string.encode("utf8")
'\xc3\xb8'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly the point. You get a byte string back, not a Unicode string. Thus the Unicode characters need to be escaped to survive. The escaping is allowed by JSON and thus presents a safe way of representing Unicode characters.

Comment: Yeah I get the point about the byte string. But is \u escape allowed in byte strings as well? Because I only saw \x escapes being used in byte string?

Comment: It's not a *Python* escape. It's a *JSON* escape.

Comment: If you don't like it when your JSON file contains those `\uXXXX` sequences, you can use `print json.dumps(unicode_string, ensure_ascii=False)`, so it returns an `unicode` rather than a byte string. I'd consider those escape sequences a legacy system for dealing with a system which mangles non-ASCII characters.

Comment: this explains why you have to escape non-ascii characters *if* the result is a bytestring *and* you want interoperability in the environment that does not accept non-ascii bytes. It doesn't explain why you can't use utf-8 instead of ascii. It doesn't explain why `json.dumps()` would return a bytestring in the first place.  `json.dumps()` *can* and *should* return a Unicode string instead. [My guess: a bytestring is used to save memory in Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32539609/4279)

Answer (score 5):

> Why does json.dumps escape non-ascii characters with “\uxxxx”

Python 2 may mix ascii-only bytestrings and Unicode strings together.

It might be a premature optimization. Unicode strings may require 2-4 times more memory than corresponding bytestrings if they contain characters mostly in ASCII range in Python 2.

Also, even today, `print(unicode_string)` may easily fail if it contains non-ascii characters while printing to Windows console unless something like `win-unicode-console` Python package is installed. It may fail even on Unix if C/POSIX locale (default for `init.d` services, `ssh`, `cron` in many cases) is used (that implies ascii character encoding. There is `C.UTF-8` but it is not always available and you have to configure it explicitly). It might explain why you might want `ensure_ascii=True` in some cases.

JSON format is defined for Unicode text and therefore strictly speaking `json.dumps()` should always return a Unicode string but it may return a bytestring if all characters are in ASCII range (`xml.etree.ElementTree` has similar "optimization"). It is confusing that Python 2 allows to treat an ascii-only bytestring as a Unicode string in some cases (implicit conversions are allowed). Python 3 is more strict (implicit conversions are forbidden).

**ASCII-only bytestrings might be used instead of Unicode strings (with possible non-ASCII characters) to save memory and/or improve interoperability in Python 2.**

To disable that behavior, use `json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=False)`.

---

It is important to avoid confusing a Unicode string with its *representation* in Python source code as Python string literal or its representation in a file as JSON text.

JSON format allows to escape any character, not just Unicode characters outside ASCII range:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(r'"\u0061"')
u'a'
>>> json.loads('"a"')
u'a'
```

Don't confuse it with escapes in Python string literals used in Python *source code*. `u"\u00f8"` is a *single* Unicode character but `"\u00f8"` in the output is *eight* characters (in Python *source code*, you could right it as `r'"\u00f8"' == '"\\u00f8"' == u'"\\u00f8"'` (backslash is special in both Python *literals* and json text -- **double escaping** may happen). Also there are no `\x` escapes in JSON:

```
>>> json.loads(r'"\x61"') # invalid JSON
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
>>> r'"\x61"' # valid Python literal (6 characters)
'"\\x61"'
>>> '"\x61"'  # valid Python literal with escape sequence (3 characters)
'"a"'
```

> The output of json.dumps() is a str, which is a byte string in Python 2. And thus shouldn't it escape characters as \xhh ?

`json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=True)` produces only printable ascii characters and therefore `print repr(json.dumps(u"\xf8"))` won't contain `\xhh` escapes that are used *to represent* (`repr()`) non-printable  chars (bytes).

`\u` escapes can be necessary even for ascii-only input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import json
print json.dumps(map(unichr, range(128)))
```

#### Output

```
["\u0000", "\u0001", "\u0002", "\u0003", "\u0004", "\u0005", "\u0006", "\u0007",
"\b", "\t", "\n", "\u000b", "\f", "\r", "\u000e", "\u000f", "\u0010", "\u0011",
"\u0012", "\u0013", "\u0014", "\u0015", "\u0016", "\u0017", "\u0018", "\u0019",
"\u001a", "\u001b", "\u001c", "\u001d", "\u001e", "\u001f", " ", "!", "\"", "#",
"$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3",
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C",
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S",
"T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "\\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", "b", "c",
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
"t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\u007f"]
```

> But isn't this quite confusing because \uxxxx is a unicode character and should be used inside a unicode string

`\uxxxx` are 6 characters that may be interpreted as a single character in some contexts e.g., in Python source code `u"\uxxxx"` is a Python literal that creates a Unicode string in memory with a *single* Unicode character. But if you see `\uxxxx` in a json text; it is *six* characters that may *represent* a single Unicode character if you load it (`json.loads()`).

At this point, you should understand why `len(json.loads('"\\\\"')) == 1`.

Comment: »Also, even today, print(unicode_string) may easily fail if it contains non-ascii characters« is probably the main point here. I'd dismiss memory usage, as most people don't routinely generate, parse, or manipulate tens of Gibibytes of JSON.

Comment: @Joey: Other things being equal, an algorithm that uses less memory is faster as a rule. I've already said that It can be considered a *premature optimization*. Printing json to console is useful for debugging (and debugging, human-readability of the format are important) but it is not hard to use utf-8 in cases where json is typically used (data exchange between programs (perhaps on different computers)) and therefore the **default should be Unicode**.

Answer (score 2):

The `\u` in `"\u00f8"` isn't actually an escape sequence like `\x`. The `\u` is a literal `r'\u'`. But such byte strings can easily be converted to Unicode.

Demo:

```
s = "\u00f8"
u = s.decode('unicode-escape')
print repr(s), len(s), repr(u), len(u)

s = "\u2122"
u = s.decode('unicode-escape')
print repr(s), len(s), repr(u), len(u)
```

**output**

```
'\\u00f8' 6 u'\xf8' 1
'\\u2122' 6 u'\u2122' 1
```

As J.F.Sebastian mentions in the comments, inside a Unicode string `\u00f8` is a true escape code, i.e., in a Python 3 string or in a Python 2 `u"\u00f8"` string. Also take heed of his other remarks!

Comment: do not use `.decode('unicode-escape')` on JSON text, use `json.loads(json_text)` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I wasn't actually suggesting the use of .decode('unicode-escape') on JSON text, merely illustrating that `"\u00f8"` etc aren't escape sequences in the sense that `'\xf8'` and `'\n'` are. And showing how to handle such sequences in a non-JSON context. Also note that the OP is talking about JSON _output_; they don't mention anything in the question about handling JSON _input_.

Comment: `\u00f8` **is** an escape sequence inside both Python unicode literal and inside a JSON text. You should not use `.decode('unicode-escape')` to fix broken bytestring literal, you should use a Unicode literal (`u''`) instead. If `\uxxxx` arrives in a variable then either json format should be used or `ast.literal_eval()` if input is a Python unicode literal and it is impossible to fix the upstream data source. It is misleading to recommend `.decode('unicode-escape')` to a beginner.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Fair enough. Is that better?