# POSTed JSON encoding problems

Tags: json, url, python-3.x, encoding

I recieve a POSTed JSON with mod_wsgi on Apache. I have to forward the JSON to some API (using POST), take API's response and respond back to where the initial POST came from.
Here goes the python code

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

def application(environ, start_response):
    url = "http://texchange.nowtaxi.ru/api/secret_api_key/"
    query = environ['QUERY_STRING']

    if query == "get":
        url += "tariff/list"
        r = requests.get(url)
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'application/json')]
    else:
        url += "order/put"
        input_len = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))
        data = environ['wsgi.input'].read(input_len)
        decoded = data.decode('utf-8')
        unquoted = urllib.parse.unquote(decoded)
        print(decoded)  # 'from%5Baddress%5D=%D0%'
        print(unquoted) # 'from[address]=\xd0\xa0'
        r = requests.post(url,data)
        output_len = sum(len(line) for line in r.text)
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'application/json'),
                            ('Content-Length', str(output_len))]

    status = "200 OK"

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [r.text.encode('utf-8')]
```

The actual JSON starts `"{"from":{"address":"Россия`
I thought those `\x`'s are called escaped symbols, so I tried `ast.literal_eval` and `codecs.getdecoder("unicode_escape")`, but it didn't help. I can't properly google the case, because I feel like I misunderstood wtf is happening here. Maybe I have to somehow change the `$.post()` call in the .js file that sends POST to the wsgi script?

**UPD:** my bro said that it's totally unclear what I need. I'll clarify. I need to get the string that represents the recieved JSON in it's initial form. With cyrillic letters, `"`s, `{}`s, etc. What I DO get after decoding recieved byte-sequence is `'from%5Baddress%5D=%D0%'`. If I unquote it, it converts into `'from[address]=\xd0\xa0'`, but that's still not what I want

Comment: read the second part of the [answer that discusses the difference between a string in memory, its text representation in Python source code and why you need to *double escape* some characters to represent a json text literally inside a Python string *literal*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32539609/4279)

Comment: @j-f-sebastian So if *any* character can be escaped, I just have to insert escaping symbol ('/', right?) before each %xx in the decoded string, instead of unquotting it?

Comment: no. It is not clear from your question what do you expect to get here: you should probably fix your client to send json text directly. If you don't know how to make a json request using javascript; ask a separate question (or more likely: find an existing question).

Comment: j-f-sebastian Pfft man, who needs easy ways :) If those portions_of_alphanumerical_chars after % satisfy Fano condition, I'll write a ~100 lettered dict :)