# Python storing Japanese word into JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, localization

I've the json data in below format and I'm trying to store it in JSON file but it's storing in encoded form in data.json file

```
data= {"a": "{0}さんではないですか？"}
    with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(json.dumps(data).encode("utf8"))
```

data.json

```
{"a": "{0}\u3055\u3093\u3067\u306f\u306a\u3044\u3067\u3059\u304b\uff1f"}
```

I want data.json to be in this format

```
{"a": "{0}さんではないですか？"}
```

I tried encoding it and then putting it in json file, no success..
can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong here and what is the right way?

Comment: it is not Chinese!

Comment: @Gang thanks for the edit, it's japanese

Comment: Why do you care what the on-disk representation is like? That is valid JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does json.dumps escape non-ascii characters with "\uxxxx"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411965/why-does-json-dumps-escape-non-ascii-characters-with-uxxxx)

Comment: @tripleee By this train of thought everything ought to be binary files (^^) -> JSON was precisely praised thanks to its human readability.

Answer (score 11):

Try using `json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=False)`.

Comment: working, thanks
another question what if I have data like {u'a: u'\u4e0d\u662f{0}?'}
and this I would like to store in data.json file?
I tried above method but it's giving me below error
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-24: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: The other answer, answers that.

Answer (score 3):

If you encode it you should also open the file as a byte array with `wb`. Because you are using `utf8` instead of `ascii` include `ensure_ascii=False` in the `json.dumps()`

Give this a try

```
import json

data= {"a": "{0}さんではないですか？"}
with open('data.json', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8"))
```

`data = {"a": "{0}さんではないですか？"}` 
and

`data = {"a": "{0}\u3055\u3093\u3067\u306f\u306a\u3044\u3067\u3059\u304b\uff1f"}`

Both gets stored as `{"a": "{0}さんではないですか？"}` in the json file.